# who_user = who_user[i][2] IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

```
i = 0
    while True:
        if i < number:
            who_user = who_user[i][2]
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, who_user)
            print(who_user)
            time.sleep(2)
            i=i+1
```

```
[('demo140405733990', '1080988492', 'Дания', 'admin'), ('demo140405733990', '1303257033', 'Mansur', 'user')] - who_user
Питон выдает непонятную ошибку, что делать.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
    while True:
        if i < number:
            who_u = who_user[i][2] # who_user в вашем коде меняет значение было who_user = [('demo140405733990', '1080988492', 'Дания', 'admin'), ('demo140405733990', '1303257033', 'Mansur', 'user')] стало who_user = 1080988492
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, who_u)
            print(who_u)
            time.sleep(2)
            i=i+1
```

мой вариант

```
for who_u in who_user:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, who_u[2])
    print(who_u)
    time.sleep(2)
```